# Repeat request to MySQL multiple times with different value if id

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, foreach

here is my code 
Please help to make it loop by  Array(0,100) for `nav_tb_id` 
Aqtualy I have a SQL stored procedure that I need to execute several times with different parameters. and get difrent rows

However I tried different ways but no result:

```
<?php 
$nav01=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nav_tb WHERE nav_tb_id = '1'");
$row_1=mysql_fetch_object($nav01);

    if ($_SESSION ['lang']==1){
       $nav_m_b_01=$row_1->RU;
    }elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==2){
       $nav_m_b_01=$row_1->UA;
    }elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==3){
       $nav_m_b_01=$row_1->EN;
    }

echo $nav_m_b_01; 


$nav02=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nav_tb WHERE nav_tb_id = '2'");
$row_2=mysql_fetch_object($nav02);

    if ($_SESSION ['lang']==1){
       $nav_m_b_02=$row_2->RU;
    }elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==2){
       $nav_m_b_02=$row_2->UA;
    }elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==3){
       $nav_m_b_02=$row_2->EN;
    }

echo $nav_m_b_02; 


...
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using MySQL query too but I'll continue your php code. You just need to wrap one of your snippets with a php do-while construct:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $nav=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nav_tb WHERE nav_tb_id = $i");
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($nav);

    if ($_SESSION ['lang']==1){

        $nav_m_b_01=$row->RU;

    } elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==2){

        $nav_m_b_01=$row->UA;

    } elseif ($_SESSION ['lang']==3){

        $nav_m_b_01=$row->EN;
    }

} while ($i < 100);
```